# Advice on securely sending a txt file from a mobile device to a server

Tags: php, android, http, post, encryption

I have to securely send a txt file from an Android device to an Apache PHP web server via HTTP. I'd like to know about the best ways this can be achieved.

The txt file can be quite large, up to 20Mb, although in most cases it will be smaller than 1Mb. I'm not sure what HTTP method would be suitable, I was considering POST.

By secure I mean that if the request is intercepted, the contents of the txt file should not be readable by anyone (not even the sender of the file). I was thinking of encrypting (I don't know how) it using a unique key generated on each Android device.

I would like to know about alternative and better ways of achieving this.

Comment: Use MD5 hashing to encrypt the text file.

Comment: @AvishekDas then how would he unhash it? And hashing is not Encrypting.

Comment: You can decrypt it because it is a one way process. And yes it is a encryption algorithm.

Comment: @AvishekDas we cannot decrypt when we use MD5

Comment: Sorry i want to write can not actually its a spelling mistake and I can't edit this.

Comment: Don't roll your own crypto. Use SSL/TLS!

Comment: I can't use HTTPS. I'm looking for suitable ways a txt file can be sent through HTTP securely.

Answer (score 1):

use this encryption file in your project

```
public class SEncryption {

private static final String ALGO = "AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'O', 'u', 'r', 'B',
'e', 's', 't','S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
Key key = generateKey();
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
Base64 ob=new Base64();
String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeBytes(encVal);
return encryptedValue;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
Key key = generateKey();
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(encryptedData);
byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
return decryptedValue;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
return key;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String password = "346333";
        String passwordEnc = encrypt(password);
        String passwordDec = decrypt(passwordEnc);

        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + password);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + passwordEnc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
    }

}
```

and for encrypting a text

```
SEncryption s=new SEncryption();
            String encryptedtext=s.encrypt("the text");
```

Comment: @PM_ME_MATH Why did I got a down vote it's a working code I use this for my projects and is working fine......

Comment: Why would this be the *best* answer? You just provided code without any reasoning. Also, don't answer questions that should be closed, since this is primarily opinion-based. (I didn't DV.)

Comment: @ArtjomB.  do you think that providing code is a malfunction which deserves a downvote.It can be used if the author of this question wish.good vision and thanks for the alert.

Comment: Certainly not. Providing code is always good on StackOverflow. It supports your point, but you have to have a point (meaning text). You should describe *why* the provided code solves the problem.

Comment: see the head part "use this encryption file in your project".I just described @ArtjomB.  how it can be implemented it's that much easy.I too had issue with finding out a good encryption method before getting the above file and so here I thought of an extended help that's all.I use to make comments than answers you can check it from my profile.Upvote is note the fact but unnecessary downvotes needs a reason right?

Comment: If you're showing code, then it should be state of the art. There are a few problems with your code: 1. Always use a fully specified Cipher string. "AES" is not enough, because other JVMs/JCE providers may have other defaults. You probably mean to use "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding". Don't use ECB! 2. You forgot to generate a random IV and prefix it to the ciphertext. 3. Encryption without authentication is not complete encryption. Either use an encrypt-then-mac scheme of simply use an authenticated block cipher mode like CCM or GCM.

Comment: ohh this's what I am using I don't have further much knowledge regarding encryption rules but it's strong upto my requirement.I'll remove the code if it's erroneus.

Answer (score 0):

Use some free encryption algorithms available on internet to encrypt the text file and use the unique android code as your key. Now send the file to the server with the unique code(key) and decrypt it there.

A simple encryption algorithm to start with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm

Comment: Why would this be the *best* answer? See, you can't say, because this question is primarily opinion-based. Also, don't answer questions that should be closed.

Comment: He's already asking to encrypt and I just directed him to a simple example to start with I never said this is the only option

Comment: @Ryan If I send the key in plaintext together with the ciphertext, wouldn't a listener be able to decipher it?

Comment: Send it on an SSH tunnel

Comment: @Ryan How do I set up an SSH tunnel with an Android device?